# C++ adapter class to wrap actual implementation

Tags: c++

Objective: "wrap" actual implementation of IPC communication bus to allow clients to interface to generic API and allow possible future replacement of underlying IPC implementation.

Here is what I came up with. Note: I'm a C-guy moving to C++.  Is there a better way of solving this problem?

Note: I want clients to interface only with my wrapper/interface and not be required to include any protocol specific code or setup include paths for implementation specific header files.

I've trolled through the design patterns.  I think I want an adapter/wrapper pattern but the order of Interface_impl : public Interface inheritance requires the client set up include paths for the specific impelementation.

The interface/wrapper is UMSConnector which calls the actual implementation UMSConnector_impl.

```
// "interface"
class UMSConnector {
public:
    static UMSConnector * instance(const string& name) {
        static UMSConnector *pInstance;
        if( ! pInstance ) {
            pInstance = new UMSConnector(name);
            return pInstance;
        }
        return pInstance;
    }

    // interface API to be implemented by UMSConnector_impl
    bool addEventHandler(string event);

private:
    class UMSConnector_impl;
    UMSConnector_impl *pImpl;
    Logger log;
    string name;

    UMSConnector(const string& name);
    ~UMSConnector();
    UMSConnector(UMSConnector const& ) {};  // copy constructor
    void operator=(const UMSConnector&) {};  // assignment constructor
};

UMSConnector::UMSConnector(const string& name)
             : name(name) {
  LOG_TRACE(log,"called");
  pImpl = new UMSConnector_impl();
}

UMSConnector::~UMSConnector() {
  LOG_TRACE(log,"called");
  delete pImpl;
  pImpl = NULL;
}

bool UMSConnector::addEventHandler(string event)
{
    if( pImpl ) {
        return pImpl->addEventHandler(event);
    }
    return false;
}

// "implementation"
class UMSConnector::UMSConnector_impl {
public:
    bool addEventHandler(const string& event);

private:
    Logger log;
};

bool UMSConnector::UMSConnector_impl::addEventHandler(const string& event)
{
  LOG_TRACE(log,"UMSConnector_impl::addEventHandler: event=%s",event.c_str());
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom you need is [PIMPL (pointer-to-implementation)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Handle_Body#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29).
Just set the `UMSConnector::addEventHandler` implementation as a call to `pImpl->addEventHandler()` and move the `UMSConnector::UMSConnector_impl` implementation to the `implementation.cpp` file with including `implementation.h` in the `interface.cpp` file. This should work as you want.